# How to fix duplicate elements in repeated protocol-buffer field?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I want to load some data using protocoll-buffers (JSON was way too slow on Android) but somehow my `repeated` field called `company` contains 6 copies of every element - although I am **not storing** any duplicates.

How do I know that it shouldn't contain duplicates?
I did set a counter for every object I am saving - and it was the expected length.

This is my schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

[...]

message CompanyProtoRepository {
    // THIS FIELD CONTAINS DUPLICATES!
    repeated CompanyProto company = 1;
}
```

How I store my data:

```java
 public void writeToFile(String fileName) {
        CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository repo = loadRepository();
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            repo.writeTo(outputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository loadRepository() {
        CompanyLoaderService jsonLoader = new JsonCompanyLoaderService(mContext.getResources());
        CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepositoryOrBuilder repo = CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository.newBuilder();
        int counter = 0; // Will be 175 which is correct (every company 1 time)
        // Will contain every id only time -> correct!
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Company company : jsonLoader.getCompanies()) {
            counter++;
            if (!map.containsKey(company.getName()))
                map.put(company.getId(), 1);
            else
                map.put(company.getId(), map.get(company.getId()) + 1);

            CompanyProtos.CompanyProto proto = toProto(company);
            if (!repo.getCompanyList().contains(proto))
                ((CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository.Builder) repo).addCompany(proto);
        }
        return ((CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository.Builder) repo).build();
    }
```

And this is how I load my data:

```java
 private List<Company> loadCompanies() {
        CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository repo = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.company_buffers);
            repo = CompanyProtos.CompanyProtoRepository.parseFrom(inputStream);
            ArrayList<Company> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (CompanyProtos.CompanyProto companyProto: repo.getCompanyList()) {
                list.add(fromProto(companyProto));
            }
            // This list contains every company 6 times!
            return list;
        } catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

Of course I expected to have each company only 1 time since I verfied that I store each company only time inside my `CompanyProtoRepository` instead of 6 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my f**** godness.
I just spent hours and hours by trying to fix that bug.
Turns out I am reading from an old corrupt data-set - and not the file I am actually writing to.